# filter data in 4 column listview android

Tags: java, android

i have a app that includes database and listview for show fetched data from database. list view has 4 columns that every column shows one column of DB. when i get data from DB method returns data in a arraylist. then i split arraylist to 4 arraylists and send it to custom adapter that gets 4 arraylist as input. PROBLEM is when i use filter in costum adapter to filter data in on column, i works for that column fine , but other columns stay unchanged , therefor related data of filtered data isn't correct and isn't related data of that row. is there a way to get correct set of data when data filtered?
please help. here is my custom adapter.

```
    package javadi60.saber.storeassistant;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> lista,listb,listc,listd;
    ArrayList<String> listb2;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Typeface tf2;
    int a;



    public CustomAdapter2(Context aplicationContext, ArrayList<String> lista, ArrayList<String> listb, ArrayList<String> listc, ArrayList<String> listd, Typeface tf2, int a) {
        this.context = context;
        this.lista = lista;
        this.listb = listb;
        this.listc = listc;
        this.listd = listd;
        this.listb2=listb;
        this.tf2 = tf2;
        this.a = a;
        inflater=(LayoutInflater.from(aplicationContext));

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listb2.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return listb2.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem2,null);
        TextView a1=view.findViewById(R.id.itemA);
        TextView a2=view.findViewById(R.id.itemB);
        TextView a3=view.findViewById(R.id.itemC);
        TextView a4=view.findViewById(R.id.itemD);
        ImageView i1=view.findViewById(R.id.item2Image);
        LinearLayout ln2=view.findViewById(R.id.item2Layout);


        i1.setImageResource(a);
        i1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        a1.setTypeface(tf2);
        a2.setTypeface(tf2);
        a3.setTypeface(tf2);
        a4.setTypeface(tf2);
        a1.setText(lista.get(i));
        a2.setText(listb2.get(i));
        a4.setText(listc.get(i));
        a3.setText(listd.get(i));




        int s=Integer.parseInt(listc.get(i));
        if (s<a){
            ln2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.list2);
        }



        return view;
    }

    public void ClearList(){
        lista.clear();
        listb.clear();
        listc.clear();
        listd.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                    //no constraint given, just return all the data. (no search)
                    results.count = listb.size();
                    results.values = listb;
                } else {//do the search
                    List<String> resultsData = new ArrayList<>();
                    String searchStr = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
                    for (String s : listb)
                        if (s.toUpperCase().contains(searchStr)) resultsData.add(s);
                    results.count = resultsData.size();
                    results.values = resultsData;
                }

                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                listb2 = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };}



}
```

as i said filter is done fine in specified column but data in other columns stay unchanged and there for row data is false .
please show me the way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of splitting the UI into 4 listviews, why don't you use a single Listview with 4 horizontal textviews (1 for each column) as below:

TextView1 | TextView2 | TextView3 | TextView4

You can use a Horizontal LinearLayout for this

Use a single adapter. This will solve your filtering issue and will also reduce the amount of work required to manage 4 different list.

```
List data = new ArrayList<Data>();

Class Data {
    String a;
    String b;
    String c;
    String d;
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. i can not use single arraylist . cause the main arraylist has data in mod a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d  string type a must be shown in  column data type b must shown in second column and.... s

Comment: thanks for answer. i use single list view . with four textviews as u said.i can not use single arraylist . cause the main arraylist has data in mod a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d  string type a must be shown in  first column String type b must shown in second column and.... so when i use single array list String a iterates in 4 text view and string type b iterates in next row in all textviews .... i also wanted to solve problem by using a hashmap instead 4 arraylists and that didnt work .

Answer (score 0):

problem solved. for whoever may face problem like my problem my problem solved by changing costumadapter like below:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import static javadi60.saber.storeassistant.setting.MyPREFERENCES;

public class CustomAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> lista,listb,listc,listd;
    ArrayList<String> listb2;
    ArrayList<String> lista2=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> listc2=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> listd2=new ArrayList<>();
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Typeface tf2;
    int a;
    List<Integer> index=new ArrayList<>();
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    public static final String TEXTSIZE="textsize";
    int txtsize;



    public CustomAdapter2(Context aplicationContext, ArrayList<String> lista, ArrayList<String> listb, ArrayList<String> listc, ArrayList<String> listd, Typeface tf2, int a) {
        this.context = context;
        this.lista = lista;
        this.listb = listb;
        this.listc = listc;
        this.listd = listd;
        this.listb2=listb;
        this.lista2=lista;
        this.listc2=listc;
        this.listd2=listd;
        this.tf2 = tf2;
        this.a = a;
        inflater=(LayoutInflater.from(aplicationContext));
        preferences = aplicationContext.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listb2.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return listb2.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem2,null);
        TextView a1=view.findViewById(R.id.itemA);
        TextView a2=view.findViewById(R.id.itemB);
        TextView a3=view.findViewById(R.id.itemC);
        TextView a4=view.findViewById(R.id.itemD);
        ImageView i1=view.findViewById(R.id.item2Image);
        LinearLayout ln2=view.findViewById(R.id.item2Layout);


        i1.setImageResource(a);
        i1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        a1.setTypeface(tf2);
        a2.setTypeface(tf2);
        a3.setTypeface(tf2);
        a4.setTypeface(tf2);

        if (preferences.contains(TEXTSIZE)){
            txtsize=preferences.getInt(TEXTSIZE,13);
        }
        a1.setTextSize(txtsize);
        a2.setTextSize(txtsize);
        a3.setTextSize(txtsize);
        a4.setTextSize(txtsize);


        a1.setText(lista2.get(i));
        a2.setText(listb2.get(i));
        a4.setText(listc2.get(i));
        a3.setText(listd2.get(i));




        int s=Integer.parseInt(listc.get(i));
        if (s<a){
            ln2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.list2);
        }



        return view;
    }

    public void ClearList(){
        lista.clear();
        listb.clear();
        listc.clear();
        listd.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                    //no constraint given, just return all the data. (no search)
                    results.count = listb.size();
                    results.values = listb;
                    index.clear();

                } else {//do the search
                    List<String> resultsData = new ArrayList<>();
                    String searchStr = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
                    List j;
                    int i=0;
                    index.clear();
                    for (String s : listb){
                        if (s.toUpperCase().contains(searchStr))
                        {
                            resultsData.add(s);
                            index.add(i);
                        }
                        i++;}

                    results.count = resultsData.size();
                    results.values = resultsData;

                }

                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                listb2 = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
                editlist();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };}

public void editlist(){
    ArrayList<String> a3=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> c3=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> d3=new ArrayList<>();
    int k=index.size();
if (index.isEmpty()){
    a3=lista;
    c3=listc;
    d3=listd;
}
else{

    for (int h=0;h<k;){
        int l=index.get(h);
        c3.add(listc.get(l));
        a3.add(lista.get(l));
        d3.add(listd.get(l));
        h++;
    }
 }   
    lista2=a3;
    listd2=d3;
    listc2=c3;
  }

}
```